# SQL Update Row with information from data from a similar Row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Last week we performed a system update, and a bunch of our customer's required due dates were changed. I am trying to figure out how to return them to their original state. Luckily, there is a row of data that has the exact information I need, I just can't figure out how to write an `UPDATE` Statement combined with the proper `LIKE` * modifier.

This is what I am dealing with:

```
 PartNo   |   Datedue   
------------------------
 G42786   |   12/31/16    --this row
 S42786   |   10/07/25   
 M42786   |   10/07/25  
 G54231   |   11/20/16    --this row
 M54321   |   01/15/22   
 S54321   |   01/15/22
```

The rows commented have the correct dates. I would like the parts that begin with M and S to be updated with that date, as long as the unique part ID (42786 and 54321) are the same as the G part. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Update:

So I backed up the table I am trying to modify and attempted to run this:

```
WITH Splitted AS
(
  SELECT LEFT(PartNo,1) AS FirstLetter
      ,CAST(SUBSTRING(PartNo,2,1000) AS INT) AS PartNumber
      ,DueDate
FROM Orderdet AS d
)
,Joined AS
(
SELECT *
FROM Splitted
     CROSS APPLY(SELECT x.DueDate FROM Splitted AS x WHERE x.FirstLetter='G'       AND x.PartNumber=Splitted.PartNumber) AS A(NewDatedue)
WHERE FirstLetter<>'G'
   )

UPDATE Joined SET Duedate=NewDatedue;
```

And I received this Error:

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '37351-0' to data type int.
```

Update:

Changed INT to Varchar in the statement and it was executed successfully. Changed the records that I was trying to update...but unfortunately with the wrong date. I'll have to do a little more exploration and find out where it pulled the date from

Comment: This error very much looks like a culture-related date-time issue... You should **really avoid** culture specific date/time formats. Your example above: What is `10/07/25`? The 10th of July in 2025? Or the 7th of October? Or maybe the 25th of July? This is an awfull format...

Comment: That is my fault. The actual data in the column is in this format:

2016-11-20 00:00:00.000

I just wrote a quick summary of what I'm looking at

Answer (score 1):

You might use an *updateable CTE*:

A *mock-up*-table

```
DECLARE @dummy TABLE(PartNo VARCHAR(100),Datedue DATE);
INSERT INTO @dummy VALUES
 ('G42786','2016-12-31')
,('S42786','2025-10-07')
,('M42786','2025-10-07')
,('G54321','2016-11-20')
,('M54321','2022-01-15')
,('S54321','2022-01-15');
```

--The first CTE will get the first letter and the PartNo separately

```
WITH Splitted AS
(
    SELECT LEFT(PartNo,1) AS FirstLetter
          ,CAST(SUBSTRING(PartNo,2,1000) AS INT) AS PartNumber
          ,Datedue
    FROM @dummy AS d
)
```

--The second CTE uses `CROSS APPLY` to get the corresponding value

```
,Joined AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM Splitted
        CROSS APPLY(SELECT x.Datedue FROM Splitted AS x WHERE x.FirstLetter='G' AND x.PartNumber=Splitted.PartNumber) AS A(NewDatedue)
    WHERE FirstLetter<>'G'
)
```

--This is updateable directly

```
UPDATE Joined SET Datedue=NewDatedue;
```

--Check the result

```
SELECT * FROM @dummy;
```

Comment: thank you for your help!  I'm still new to this so it's going to take me a little bit to research and figure out what you wrote actually means. I'll let you know what I find. much appreciated

Comment: @Wes, never mind... Take the time needed... To check this: Just copy the whole lot *as is* into a new query window and execute. This is a fully working test scenario...

Comment: much appreciated. I will let you know how it goes!

Comment: @wes just be careful doing this... what Shnugo has provided is a test example since he uses a table variable. Be sure it does just what you want before you replace that table variable, `@dummy`, with your real table since it will update accordingly. IMHO i'd back up your DB or at least copy that table with a different name. I only stress this because you stated you are researching what his code does. It's a great example as long as you know what it does.

Comment: sounds good thanks scsimon. that is the one thing I have managed to figure out---I only experiment inside of a back up of our real database.  But copying the table with a different name is a good tip, when I make mistakes in the back up database it's still a pain to copy it again.